# Local Notifications received, even after app is uninstalled?

Tags: iphone, ios4

Has anybody had the experience of Local Notifications being delivered from an app that has been uninstalled? I hesitate to ask since I can't reliably reproduce the issue, but we're receiving multiple reports of that occurring.

We're having an emergency debug session here, and since we barely know where to start looking for answers on this, wanted to see if anybody else has had this happen to them, as either a developer or as a consumer.  Could this potentially be an iOS 4.0 bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there's a thread on it here: https://devforums.apple.com/message/253796

Likely an iOS bug.